# How can java start a new jdk environment?

Tags: process, java

I have packaged a separated codes to a new jar. I want it run in a new jre(with its own heap memory), can this code works for me? Or any best practise?

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -classpath . com.company.Runner");
```

Comment: technically yes, it should work.

Comment: assuming `java.exe` is in your PATH variable, yes. it should work